# Python - using dictionary to count keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am a student in a python course where we created a list of tuples (containing 2 elements) that we're trying to manipulate in various ways. In addition, we are to convert those tuple elements into a dictionary and re-create the manipulations using the dictionary and avoiding for loops. The task I'm stuck on is that given a specific id (which could be a key OR value in the dictionary) the function returns all the other keys/values that are found in that dictionary.

It doesn't seem efficient to use a dictionary for this, but that's the section we are on in the course and is specifically asked by the assignment. Also no for loops (if that is possible?). Recall that the id can be either a key or a value in the dictionary.

```
example_dictionary = {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'}

def get_interactions(example_dictionary, id):
    output = ''
    for j,k in example_dictionary.items():
        if j == id:
            output = output + k + ' '
        if k == id:
            output = output + j + ' '
    return output
```

This code works just fine, however it 1) has a for loop (no good) and 2) isn't very pythonic (kind of an eyesore)! How could I use the dictionary more efficiently and condense down my lines? I am in Python 3, Thank you!

Comment: dict.keys() might work

Comment: Weren't you given any hints as to how it could be solved *without* `for` loops? It seems strange for a teacher to throw that requirement into the mix without going through some alternative approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Expected result

Having one dictionary and value named `wanted`, you want to create another dict being copy of
original one with removed all items not having key or value equal to `wanted` value.

It can be expressed in form of pytest test case with couple of scenarios.

```
import pytest
scenarios = [
    [
        # dct
        {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'},
        # wanted
        "A",
        # expected (result)
        {'A': 'C', 'D': 'A'},
    ],
    [
        # dct
        {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'},
        # wanted
        "E",
        # expected (result)
        {'R': 'E'},
    ],
    [
        # dct
        {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'},
        # wanted
        "D",
        # expected (result)
        {'D': 'A', 'C': 'D'},
    ],
    [
        # dct
        {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'},
        # wanted
        "nothere",
        # expected (result)
        {},
    ],
    [
        # dct
        {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'},
        # wanted
        "A",
        # expected (result)
        {'A': 'C', 'D': 'A'},
    ],
]


# replace with real implementation
def get_key_or_val_itms(dct, wanted):
    # something comes here
    return result

@pytest.mark.parametrize("scenario", scenarios)
def test_it(scenario):
    dct, wanted, expected = scenario
    assert get_key_or_val_itms(dct, wanted) == expected
```

Do not bother with anything apart from `scenarios`. It lists couple of test scenarios with input
dictionary, value for `wanted` and expected result.

## Building stones for the solution

### dict.items() - dict to list of tuples

```
>>>  dct = {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'}
>>>  dct.items()
[('A', 'C'), ('R', 'E'), ('D', 'A'), ('L', 'R'), ('C', 'D')]
```

### testing membership of a value in a tuple/list

```
>>> 'A'  in ('A', 'C')
True
>>> 'A'  in ('R', 'E')
False
```

### Lambda function testing, if `wanted` is present in a tuple

`lambda` allows "in place" function definition. It is often used in places,
where some functions expects reference to a function.

First, create named function `tuple_wanted`

```
>>> wanted = "A"
>>> def tuple_wanted(tpl):
...    return wanted in tpl
```

and test it (note, that `wanted` has now value "A"):

```
>>> tuple_wanted(('A', 'C'))
True
>>> tuple_wanted(('R', 'E'))
False
```

Now create the function. To play with it, we store the result of `lambda` in `fun`:

```
>>> fun = lambda tpl: wanted in tpl
```

It can be used in the same manner a `tuple_wanted` before:

```
>>> fun(('A', 'C'))
True
>>> fun(('R', 'E'))
False
```

Later on we will use the result of `lambda` directly (see `filter`) without
storing it into any variable.

### `filter` removing all list items not passing some test

`filter` gets test function and iterable (e.g. list of items) to test by it.

Result of calling `filter` is list of items from the iterable, which passed the test.

In our case, we want to pass only the tuples, containing `wanted` value (e.g. "A")

```
>>> filter(tuple_wanted, dct.items())
    [('A', 'C'), ('D', 'A')]
>>> filter(fun, dct.items())
    [('A', 'C'), ('D', 'A')]
>>> filter(lambda tpl: wanted in tpl, dct.items())
    [('A', 'C'), ('D', 'A')]
```

### Convert list of tuples with 2 items into dictionary

```
>>> tpllst = [('A', 'C'), ('D', 'A')]
>>> dict(tpllst)
    {'A': 'C', 'D': 'A'}
```

## Function doing the work

### Long version

This version is here to explain what is going on step by step:

```
def get_key_or_val_itms(dct, wanted):
    # dict as [(key, val), (key2, val2), ...]
    tpldct = dct.items()
    # find tuples, where either key or val equals `wanted` value
    # first make function, which detects, the tuple we search for

    def tuple_wanted(tpl):
        return wanted in tpl
    # now use it to filter only what we search for
    restpldct = filter(tuple_wanted, tpldct)
    # finally, turn the result into dict
    return dict(restpldct)
```

### Short version

```
def get_key_or_val_itms(dct, wanted):
    return dict(filter(lambda tpl: wanted in tpl, dct.items()))
```

## Conclusions

It works (with either long or short version of the function):

```
>>> dct = {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'}
>>> wanted = "A"
>>> get_key_or_val_itms(dct, wanted)
{'A': 'C', 'D': 'A'}
```

If you put the function into file with test suite, calling `$ py.test -sv the_file.py` shall output:

```
$ py.test -sv the_file.py
py.test================================ test session starts =========================
=======
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /home/javl/
.virtualenvs/stack/bin/python2
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/javl/sandbox/stack/dict, inifile:
collected 5 items

countdict.py::test_it[scenario0] PASSED
countdict.py::test_it[scenario1] PASSED
countdict.py::test_it[scenario2] PASSED
countdict.py::test_it[scenario3] PASSED
countdict.py::test_it[scenario4] PASSED

============================= 5 passed in 0.01 seconds ==============================
```

As can be seen, all the scenarios are passing.

Explanation how `py.test` works is out of scope of this answer, to learn more about it, see http://pytest.org/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions, although one could argue that it is a kind of for loop:

```
example_dictionary = {'A': 'C', 'R': 'E', 'D': 'A', 'L': 'R', 'C': 'D'}   
def get_interactions(dic, id):
    output =[v for k, v in dic.items() if k == id] + [k for k,v in dic.items() if v == id]
    return output
```

Comment: This code is very nice, thank you for sharing! However, when I run it, it is only returning the id that is the argument of the function, and not it's paired key/value?

Comment: I misunderstood the desired output, my bad; I have edited the answer to match. Note that this code is for Python 2.7. It can easily be adapted to Python 3.

Comment: I tested this code in Python 3 and it works as is. So, no adaptation needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know how to avoid using a for loop, other than making your own for loop, similar to the following:

```
i = 0
def func(tup, id) {
    if i < len(dictionary_items):        
        output = False

        if tup[0] == id or tup[1] == id:
            output = id + ' '

        i += 1

        return output
}

dictionary_items = dictionary.items()

func(dictionary_items[0], id)
func(dictionary_items[1], id)
func(dictionary_items[2], id)
```

And so on. However, that would be ugly and extremely non-pythonic.

As for making your code more pythonic, you can change the lines `output = output + k + ' '` to `output += k + ' '` or `output = k + ' '` (You're concatenating strings k and ' ' to an empty string, output, which changes nothing about the strings k and ' ').
Furthermore, you could check `if j == id or k == id` rather than two seperate if statements, then saying `output = id + ' '`,since if j or k are equal to id, it doesn't matter if you return whichever of j and k is equal to the id or if you return the id itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all the keys and values, so there is always going to be some type of loop.  Python has many ways to iterate (ie. loop) through items without explicit use of `for`.

One good way to iterate through items without `for` is with the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) built-in functions along with the `lambda` syntax for creating small, anonymous functions.

```
from itertools import chain

# Get values for matching keys and vice versa
values = map(lambda x: x[1] if x[0] == id else None, dct.items())
keys = map(lambda x: x[0] if x[1] == id else None, dct.items())

# Then you filter out the None values 
# itertools.chain allows us to conveniently do this in one line
matches = filter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(keys, values))
```

If you can't use `itertools.chain`, you'll just need a few extra steps

```
keys = filter(lambda x: x is not None, keys)
values = filter(lambda x: x is not None, values)
matches = keys + values
```

If you need a space separated output of values:

```
output = ' '.join(matches)
```